# Diminuir um base64

Tags: java, android, base64

Como diminuir um tamanho de um base64 sem diminuir tanto a qualidade?Estou tento um problema nesse codigo,porque está muito grande e não está salvando no banco. Como diminuir ?

```
    Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    byte[] b = bytes.toByteArray();
    String encodedfile = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);


    base64p = encodedfile;
```

Comment: Tiago o caractere `>` é pra ser usado para citar algo na pergunta, não para destacar todo o texto dela. Procure usar a citação somentre quando for necessário.

Comment: @Thiago Você realmente precisa salvar um base64 no banco de dados? Não pode ser um BLOB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tecnicamente na linha

```
thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
```

você não está tratando nada na imagem, somente trocando o formato dela.

O que você tem que fazer é, antes de fazer a conversão, é tratar a imagem.
Usando como exemplo a biblioteca Compressor (https://github.com/zetbaitsu/Compressor), você pode tratar a imagem antes de converter para Base64 (sendo que o tratamento TEM que ser feito na imagem antes da conversão).

Mas conforme o @Marquezani comentou na sua pergunta, existe a real necessidade de gravar a base64, n poderia por exemplo gravar os bytes da imagem ou a imagem em si num BLOB?