# Comprimir tamanho de imagem

Tags: java, android

Como comprimir o tamanho de uma imagem, de forma que ela fique com um tamanho menor ?

```
  public void onCaptureImageResult(Intent data) {
    Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, bytes);
    byte[] b = bytes.toByteArray();
    String encodedfile = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);


    base64p = encodedfile;


    System.out.println(base64p);


    File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
            System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
```

Comment: Não conheço em Java, mas utilizo esse serviço para esse fim. Inclusive, eles possuem uma API que tem um excelente resultado de compressão. Caso lhe seja útil, segue o link: https://tinypng.com.

Comment: Duplicou sua própria pergunta: [Diminuir um base64](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/224257/diminuir-um-base64)

Answer (score 0):

Tente usar essa biblioteca. É simples e fácil de utilizar.

[Compressor](https://github.com/zetbaitsu/Compressor)

Answer (score 0):

Tente algo semelhante a isso:

```
    /**
 * Redimensiona a imagem.
 *
 * @return array de bytes com imagem redimensionada
 */
private static byte[] resizeImage(byte[] imageByte, int width, int height) throws IOException {
    try (InputStream inputImage = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageByte);) {
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(inputImage);
        BufferedImage imgResized = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        imgResized.getGraphics().drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height, null);
        return imageToByte(imgResized);
    }
}
```

Sendo imageToByte este método:

```
    /**
 * Converte BufferedImage para array de bytes no formato JPG.
 *
 */
private static byte[] imageToByte(BufferedImage img) throws IOException {
    return imageToByte(img, ImageType.JPG);
}
```

imagesToByte:

```
    /**
 * Converte BufferedImage para array de bytes.
 *
 */
private static byte[] imageToByte(BufferedImage img, ImageType tipoImagem) throws IOException {
    try (ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();) {
        ImageIO.write(img, tipoImagem.getValue(), baos);
        baos.flush();
        return baos.toByteArray();
    }
}
```

O enum que ele passa como parâmetro é este:

```
public enum ImageType {
JPG("jpg"), PNG("png"), JPEG("jpeg");
```

Este método funciona perfeitamente. Dúvidas estou a disposição.